# Unable to set breakpoint in ipython command line when spyder is used

Tags: debugging, ipython, spyder, breakpoints, magic-command

Hi =) I understand that I can run an ipython debugger and set a breakpoint at the command line, e.g.

```
%run -d -b12 convert_excel.py
```

However, I am unable to get Spyder (version 5.4.3) to recognise the `-b12` command.

An example script to reproduce this problem is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Apr 14 18:12:11 2023

@author: jonathan

Convert CPIC excel files into text files
"""

import pandas as pd

INPUT_FOLDER = 'raw_excel'
FILE = 'raw_excel/test.xlsx' 

df_dict = pd.read_excel(FILE, index_col=0, sheet_name=None)  

for key in df_dict:
    if 'CDS' in df_dict[key].columns.str.cat(sep = ' '):
        drug_df = df_dict[key]
        output = FILE.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] + '.txt'
        drug_df.to_csv(output, sep='\t')
```

When I run this code `%run -d -b12 convert_excel.py`, my  breakpoint is ignored. The below is what I see:

```
In [9]: %run -d -b12 convert_excel.py
Breakpoint 1 at c:\users\jonat\documents\machine_learning\genetic_pipeline\convert_excel.py:12
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
> c:\users\jonat\documents\machine_learning\genetic_pipeline\convert_excel.py(2)<module>()
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 2 """
      3 Created on Fri Apr 14 18:12:11 2023
      4 
      5 @author: jonathan


IPdb [1]: b

IPdb [2]: c
C:\Users\jonat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py:226: UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default
  warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")
```

If I set the breakpoint directly in ipython, instead of setting it with the `%run` command, it works:

```
In [12]: %run -d convert_excel.py
*** Blank or comment
*** Blank or comment
*** Blank or comment
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
> c:\users\jonat\documents\machine_learning\genetic_pipeline\convert_excel.py(2)<module>()
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 2 """
      3 Created on Fri Apr 14 18:12:11 2023
      4 
      5 @author: jonathan


IPdb [1]: b 12
Breakpoint 1 at c:\users\jonat\documents\machine_learning\genetic_pipeline\convert_excel.py:12

IPdb [2]: b
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at c:\users\jonat\documents\machine_learning\genetic_pipeline\convert_excel.py:12

IPdb [3]: c
> c:\users\jonat\documents\machine_learning\genetic_pipeline\convert_excel.py(12)<module>()
     10 import pandas as pd
     11 
1--> 12 INPUT_FOLDER = 'raw_excel'
     13 FILE = 'raw_excel/fluvastatin_Pre_and_Post_Test_Alerts.xlsx'
     14
```

May I know why doesnt Spyder recognise the `b` command in `%run` and how do I fix this?